# Wfi wont connect to the internet after hardisk replacement

Tags: windows, wifi-driver

Im using a HP probook 6460b and my hdd died so i got a replacement hdd and reinstalled windows and drivers manually but the wifi can connect to a network but not the internet

Comment: check to make sure your ipv4 address is set to automatic and not static

Comment: do you mind walking me through it?

Comment: go to network and sharing center--> click "change adapter settings" on the left side of the screen--> right click on your wifi adapter and click properties--> click "internet protocol version 4" (or something like this) and click properties--> make sure that both options are set to "obtain....automatically". If they already are, you have a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution (as mentioned by OP above)

check to make sure your ipv4 address is set to automatic and not static. Steps to do this:

go to network and sharing center--> click "change adapter settings" on the left side of the screen--> right click on your wifi adapter and click properties--> click "internet protocol version 4" (or something like this) and click properties--> make sure that both options are set to "obtain....automatically".

Comment: Which is somethung work works (and only works) if you have a DHCP server.

Comment: as most people do